# Sharing LiveData in a singleton

Tags: android, repository, android-livedata

Is sharing an instance of LiveData not a bad practice if the value is posted in a constructor of a singleton? I was looking at [architecture samples](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/BasicSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/persistence/DataRepository.java) and was questioning if this was a good practice. I read it from a [post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-beyond-the-viewmodel-reactive-patterns-using-transformations-and-mediatorlivedata-fda520ba00b7) that sharing instances of LiveData is an antipattern. If you see the code below, it is sharing `mObservableProducts`. The value is set in the constructor of the class.

```
public class DataRepository {

    private static DataRepository sInstance;

    private final AppDatabase mDatabase;
    private MediatorLiveData<List<ProductEntity>> mObservableProducts;

    private DataRepository(final AppDatabase database) {
        mDatabase = database;
        mObservableProducts = new MediatorLiveData<>();

        mObservableProducts.addSource(mDatabase.productDao().loadAllProducts(),
                productEntities -> {
                    if (mDatabase.getDatabaseCreated().getValue() != null) {
                        mObservableProducts.postValue(productEntities);
                    }
                });
    }

    public static DataRepository getInstance(final AppDatabase database) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            synchronized (DataRepository.class) {
                if (sInstance == null) {
                    sInstance = new DataRepository(database);
                }
            }
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    /**
     * Get the list of products from the database and get notified when the data changes.
     */
    public LiveData<List<ProductEntity>> getProducts() {
        return mObservableProducts;
    }
}
```